# Apply exiftran recursivly (rotate all images based on their EXIF info)

Tags: find, image-processing, jpeg, exiftool

I would like to execute [`exiftran`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/exiftran) on all .jpg files recursively below the current directory.

`exiftran -ai *` does what I need (apply rotation based on EXIF info) within the current directory, but not within subdirectories.

Is there a flag I don't know of? Or a workaround using `find`?

Answer (score 2):

I finally used find to achieve this:

`find . -type f -name "*.jpg" -exec exiftran -ai "{}" \;`